# Read multiple comma separated doubles from a string

Tags: c++, string, double, type-conversion

I need to get some doubles from a string.

```
string data = getMyData();
char** next;
double start = strtod(data.c_str(), next);

if (&data == &(*next)) //check wether a double has been found - not working
{
    std::cerr << "Value can't be read.\nAborting.";
    return;
}
```

My idea is to check for memory address of data's first char and next.
At the moment I'm learning C++ in self education so it would be nice to get the best solution and not just a working one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
char* next;
double start = strtod(data.c_str(), &next);

if (data.c_str() == next)
```

Remember that `next` will point to the next *comma* if these are comma-separated, not the beginning of the next number.

Comment: Yeah I know. That's my next step.